# How to handle for loop with promises conditionally

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, promise, async-await

I am still trying to find a way to handle promises in a loop conditionally with the ability to break out of the loop.

Here is a short example

```
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                    if (ipAddresses.length > 0) {
                        let currentServer, agentOptions;
                        for (let i = 0; i < ipAddresses.length; i++) {
                            currentServer = ipAddresses[i];
                            agentOptions = {
                            };
                           // We need to block here
                            let isReachable = NetworkUtils.checkIfReachable(agentOptions, ip);
                            if (isReachable) {
                                resolve(currentServer);
                                // Break out of the loop
                                return currentServer;
                            }
                            else {
                                // Continue looping and trying to find a working server
                            }
                        }
                        reject(new Error("No working servers found"));
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve(new Error("No servers ips provided"));
                    }
                })
```

The problem is that I don't need to run all requests in parallel lie `Promise.all` or `async.foreach`, but I rather need to call each promise sequentually and if condition is true I need to break out the loop and do not make any further requests as far as I have found a reachable server.

Please suggest what is the correct way to handle this use case. I have been searching for a long time, but still haven't found any good solution.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Sorry, yeah `NetworkUntils.checkIfReachable()` returns promise

Comment: is `NetworkUtils.checkIfReachable(agentOptions, ip)` a synchronous request?

Comment: I think [`Promise.race()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) is what you're looking for.

Comment: If you "don't need to run all requests in parallel like Promise.all" or do async requests, I ask why do you need promises?

Comment: Your code seems to indicate that `NetworkUtils.checkIfReachable()` is synchronous (though that seems unlikely).  If it is synchronous, then you don't need promises at all.  You can just run a regular `for` loop and return when an answer is found - no promises.  If `NetworkUtils.checkIfReachable()` is actually asynchronous, then show us the async interface it has so we can code appropriately for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `NetworkUntils.checkIfReachable()` is actually asynchronous (which is the only context in which this question makes sense and seems likely in nodejs) and assuming that `NetworkUntils.checkIfReachable()` returns a promise or can easily be changed to return a promise, then you can do the following:

```
findFirstReachableServer(ipAddresses) {
    if (!ipAddresses || !ipAddresses.length) {
        return Promise.reject(new Error("No servers ips provided"));
    }
    let agentOptions = {...};
    let index = 0;
    function next() {
        if (index < ipAddresses.length) {
            let ipAddress = ipAddresses[index++];
            return NetworkUtils.checkIfReachable(agentOptions, ipAddress).then(function(isReachable) {
                if (!isReachable) {
                    return next();
                } else {
                    return ipAddress;
                }
            })
        } else {
            return new Error("No working servers found");
        }
    }
    return Promise.resolve().then(next);
}
```

This function returns a promise that resolves with the ipAddress if a reachable one was found.  It rejects if either no addresses were passed in, no reachable address was found or if `NetworkUtils.checkIfReachable()` rejects for any internal reason.

Note, to run non-blocking async operations in sequence, you can't use a normal `for` loop because each individual operation won't block so the `for` loop won't wait for them (it will just run to completion before any operations have finished).  As such, you have to use a different method of sequencing.  There are lots of different ways to do that.  Since you don't necessarily want to run the entire sequence, I've chosen a manual sequencing where you control whether the next iteration is called or not.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I got your idea, but it seems to be similar to my described in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675178/how-to-run-same-promises-one-after-another-nodejs

Could you tell me what is wrong with my code there (please answer that question)

Comment: @bxfvgekd - I've already written you one solution from scratch.  Why not just use this one?  I don't really care to solve this same problem a second time.  FYI, your other solution has all sorts of [promise anti-patterns in it](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) so I would never do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Given you tagged the question [async-await](/questions/tagged/async-await), using that is not a bad idea indeed:

```
async function findWorkingServer(ipAddresses) {
    if (ipAddresses.length > 0) {
        for (const currentServer of ipAddresses) {
            const agentOptions = { … };
            const isReachable = await NetworkUtils.checkIfReachable(agentOptions, ip);
//          We do "block" here  ^^^^^
            if (isReachable) {
                return currentServer;
            }
        }
        throw new Error("No working servers found");
    } else {
        return new Error("No servers ips provided"); // I think you meant to `throw` here
    }
}
```